# Rails Query different order depend on a column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this query in MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Employee
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN is_outsourcing = 'true' THEN Country END Desc,
CASE WHEN is_outsourcing = 'false' THEN joined_date END ASC
```

I tried to make a rails query so that all is_outsourcing employees is ordered first and their order is decided by their country. The rest of the employees is ordered by joined_date.

Currently, I got this query to order by is_outsoucing first:

```
User.all.order(is_outsourcing DESC)
```

But I don't know how to do the later part. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put `order by` logic as a string:

```
User.all.
  order("CASE WHEN is_outsourcing = 'true' THEN Country END Desc,
         CASE WHEN is_outsourcing = 'false' THEN joined_date END ASC")
```